# Is there a way for my spring-boot controller to know a button was pushed in the interface associated?

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring boot with maven to develop a a marketplace, i have my items listed in a template and when you over an item, you can add it to your cart, my question is, how to i tell my controller that a specific button on the template was pressed? I know that using django I could just check if a specific post request was made and so something with it after, but I have no idea how to do so using spring
Here's the code:

shop controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/shop/{type}",  method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
    public String shop(@PathVariable String type, String movietag, Model model, Principal principal){
        if (movietag == null)
            model.addAttribute("products", productService.listAll());
        else
            model.addAttribute("products", productService.findByMovietag(movietag));
        model.addAttribute("productSearch", new Product());
        model.addAttribute("title", "Shop");
        model.addAttribute("title2", "Check out all the new Movie Arrivals Collection 2020");
        model.addAttribute("type", type);
        model.addAttribute("day", java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now()));
        if (principal == null) {
            model.addAttribute("cart", null);
        } else {
            Customer customer = customerService.findCustomerByEmail(principal.getName());
            model.addAttribute("cart", customer.getCart());
        }
        return "shop";
    }
```

shop template:

```
<!-- Product -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div th:each="product: ${products}" th:if="${(type=='all') or (type=='new' and product.getDate().equals(day)) or (type=='sale' and product.getPrice()<product.getOldPrice())}" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 p-b-50">
                            <!-- Block2 -->
                            <div class="block2">
                                <div class="block2-img wrap-pic-w of-hidden pos-relative" th:classappend="${product.getDate().equals(day)} ? 'block2-labelnew'">
                                    <img th:src="${product.getImage()}" alt="IMG-PRODUCT">

                                    <div class="block2-overlay trans-0-4">
                                        <div class="block2-btn-addcart w-size1 trans-0-4">
                                            <!-- Button -->
                                            <button class="flex-c-m size1 bg4 bo-rad-23 hov1 s-text1 trans-0-4">
                                                Add to Cart 
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="block2-txt p-t-20">
                                    <a href="item.html" th:href="@{|/item/${product.getProductId()}|}" th:text="${product.getName()}" class="block2-name dis-block s-text3 p-b-5"></a>
                                    <span th:if="${product.getPrice()<product.getOldPrice()}" th:text="'$'+${product.getOldPrice()}" class="block2-oldprice m-text7 p-r-5"></span>
                                    <span th:text="'$'+${product.getPrice()}" class="block2-price p-r-5" th:classappend="${product.getPrice()<product.getOldPrice()} ? 'm-text8' : 'm-text6'"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "a specific post request"? I don't see a form in your HTML, so if you're using something like AJAX, that's important.

Comment: I'm not using ajax, i just wanted to know, how do i tell my controller that the button was clicked?

Comment: Are you familiar with how HTTP form posts work?

Comment: Oof r/Roasted, is just that I only ever used django, so not really sure how do i separate my post (button actions) from the rest of the other requests withing the same function

Comment: It's just a bit unclear exactly what you're trying to make your controller do. It's also unusual to have a single controller method handle both GET and POST, since GET is (usually) "retrieve a thing" and POST is (usually) "create or update a thing".

Comment: I found a solution, by using this `method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET}` I'm able to use both requests type and then I used what I used to use in django  `if (request.getMethod().equals("POST")){` and it works the same way, thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the id of the button to the controller and can handle the subsequent logic in the controller.

you can get the id of the button onSubmit() event of the button and set the id in the request header and retrieve it in the controller.

Comment: so if I pass the id how to do I proceed to check if the button was clicked or not? and how many times

Comment: you can either maintain the relationship of the id and button type of server side or send the button type in the header instead of id. I assumed you are going to send the list of objects in the cart on click of the mentioned button.  But, if your requirement is to identify which type of button was used to add a product to the cart, then you need to keep the type of button in the object POJO and should be set for every click of add to card. The details can be extracted in the controller from Header incase of scenario 1, or from the POJO object for the scenario 2.